# Color adjustment for 100 jpg files: Fast workflow for save+next

Tags: colors, gimp, workflow

I want to do manual color adjustment for 100 jpg files.

The workflow I use at the moment works like this:

1. open first jpg in gimp.
2. do manual color adjustment. Either "auto" or "curves"
3. save jpg (overwrite)
4. load next jpg

The above workflow is slow. A lot of time gets wasted by loading and saving.

I want to do a **manual** correction of each photo. This question is not about batch processing.

I want the switching (save current, go to next) to be fast as using a flipbook.

I am not married with gimp. Any tool that can do color adjustment via curves would fit.

Any hint how to do this?

Comment: As you may know, gimp comes with some built-in scripting capability; mine (of 14.04) has `Python-Fu` and `Script-Fu` at the foot of the `Filters` menu. I have not used them myself, but I'd believe you could shape one or both of those into doing something useful.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist I can do software development. But sometimes I put on my "I am a user - not a geek" glasses.  I think there should be a way to solve this without scripting.

Comment: Right. And `gimp-remote` isn't of use either I suppose. Admittedly I'm too geek-ish myself to really understand which aspect of this you're aiming to improve. Maybe you have exhausted the attribute combinations of `ImageMagick` as well?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist `ImageMagick` is for batch processing. I want to apply an individual color curve by hand on each image. I don't understand what you mean with "Maybe you have exhausted the attribute combinations of ImageMagick as well? "

Comment: No offense intended. Maybe the GAP plugin to gimp  (http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Using_GAP/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [darktable](http://www.darktable.org/) is a valuable option here, you will find it in the Ubuntu Software Center or you can install it in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install darktable
```

Here is the work-flow I would suggest:

### Import images

Import the images you want to edit by using the top left `Import` menu:

[image: lighttable]

### Mark you favorite modules

Double click on an image thumbnail to switch to the darkroom. On the bottom right choose your favorite modules buy using the drop-down menu `more modules`:

[image: more modules]

Stared modules are in the "Favorite" tab.

### Edit your images

Go to your favorite modules by clicking on the star icon just below the histogram, edit your image by adding points to the curve etc. (right click on the sliders to get cool UIs, or just type in the value directly!)

[image: adjust image]

When you are done with one image, just double click on the next image in the bottom photo strip.

### Faster tweaking

When the same (or near) processing can be applied to several images, switch back to the `lighttable` (top menu).

Select your image by single clicking the thumbnail. Use the `history stack` to copy some modules parameters:

[image: history stack]

After that select the destination images and hit the `paste` or `paste all` button in the `history stack` menu.

### Export your images

When you are satisfied with the images go back to the lighttable and use the export menu in the right panel, select the images you want to export first (`Ctrl+A` to select all):

[image: export]

Comment: This workflow is slow (today) since I am new to darktable. But I think switching from gimp to darktable is worth the effort. I guess after learning it, I will be much faster. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: One thing I stumbled about: overwriting the existing images seems difficult. Like in gimp the perfectionists creating the software try to force their rules on the user: You must not load, edit and overwrite jpg files. I am not a perfectionist. I want to load, edit and overwrite jpg files. But I guess I can solve this. With darktable the saving (called "export" in darktable) happens at end (after editing N images).

Comment: Here is the question "Load, edit overwrite jpg files with darktable"  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71992/load-edit-overwrite-jpg-files-with-darktable

Comment: What a great and handy tool! Thanks for sharing existence of darktable <3

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gimp /path/to/file` and script it to iterate over all the file names, however, you would need to either reinitialize gimp each time or set a time limit for the next iteration. Also, you would need to overwrite manually.

While I know this isn't the best form:

```
for i in $(ls *.jpg)
do
  gimp $i
done
```

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? Loading gimp again and again takes some time. And gimp ask several times, since it prefers to save with his custom file format. Exporting to jpg needs special handling. Ctrl-s does not work. This could be improved by using `xargs -n 10` to load 10 images at once. But still not a very fast workflow.

Comment: Admittedly, I haven't. It's not perfect, but I'm stumped on what else you could do. Except maybe a background job for the `gimp $i` and a read after. That was you can keep the same gimp environment.